# Is Assign a Value Out of Range to a Signed Var Undefined in C++ Standard

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've been read C++ Primer, it said if I assign a value out of range to a signed var will make the var be undefined, but the result of experiment in Visual C++ compiler is same as unsigned var, it will drop higher bits in binary, is that feature in C++ standard? Visual C++ broke it?

Comment: Oh, I am exactly asking about C++

Comment: And I am asking about assign variable in function (assign local variable)

Comment: It would improve the question to post code that you are asking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of integral conversions is defined in C++17 [conv.integral]:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

There is no undefined behaviour. Furthermore, results of experiments can never tell you anything because you don't know if you are seeing undefined behaviour or not. The only reliable method is to check the Standard. And if the standard says "implementation-defined" then you check your compiler's documentation  to see what the definition is.

---

This will probably change in C++20, the new text from the latest standard draft is:

> the result is the unique value of the destination type that is congruent to the source integer modulo 2<sup>N</sup> , where N is the width of the destination type.

which is formal language for "discard high bits in 2's complement representation".

Comment: And Visual C++ already accord to C++ 20 variable assign standard?

Comment: @AlanJian Either C++ Primer is not correct, or you misquoted it .  You would have to consule the VC++ documentation to answer your second question